# How would I convert this c# code to vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

Hello I found this code online and it seems to do what I want. However it it written in c# which I'm not familiar with. Any polyglot programmers out there who can convert this to vb.net? I greatly appreciate any help you may give!

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn clm in grdView.Columns)
{
Bool FoundData = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
{
     if (row.Cells[clm.Index].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
     {
         FoundData = true;
         break;
     }
}
if (!FoundData)
{
     grdView.Columns[clm.Index].Visible = false;
}
}
```

Comment: try with converter : http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each clm As DataGridViewColumn In grdView.Columns
    Dim FoundData As Boolean = False
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdView.Rows
        If row.Cells(clm.Index).Value.ToString() <> String.Empty Then
            FoundData = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not FoundData Then
        grdView.Columns(clm.Index).Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 for a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any online conversion tool. http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

```
 For Each clm As DataGridViewColumn In grdView.Columns
   Dim FoundData As Bool = false
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdView.Rows
    If (row.Cells(clm.Index).Value.ToString <> string.Empty) Then
        FoundData = true
        Exit For
    End If
 Next
 If Not FoundData Then
    grdView.Columns(clm.Index).Visible = false
 End If
 Next
```

Comment: `Bool` is not a valid VB.NET type. You took the conversion too literally.

Comment: It's not a valid C# type either - garbage in garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool. You might find it helpful for future conversions:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/